# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: invalid address (arg="", coderType="address"

Tags: web3js, javascript

First of all, i extracting function from abi of my contract and calling them automatically. As per documentation of solidity, when we compile .sol, some functions are automatically generated as per our contract specs. For, example, if i write in my contract `mapping( address => uint256) public  balances`, it will generate function namely **balances** and taking **address** as input (argument). When my program call this function (with properly given valid address), it causes error. I am confused why I could not find any solution for this. Although i have given all kind of inputs as per requirement of my contract. Still getting such error. 
Here is my code

```
async function genericGetterFunction(receipt, key){
  var funcParmLength
  var myFunc; 
  var  myContAddr = receipt.contractAddress;
  var myContractAbiDefenition = sources[key].abi;
  var myContractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(myContractAbiDefenition, myContAddr);

  for(j=0; j < getterFunctionsNameObject[key].length; j++){
      myFunc = getterFunctionsNameObject[key][j].func;
      funcParmLength  = (getterFunctionsNameObject[key][j].input).length;
      console.log("param length: ", funcParmLength)
      if (funcParmLength ==0)
          res = await myContractInstance.methods[myFunc]().call({from: account1, value: web3.utils.toWei('0', 'ether')})
      else 
          res = await myContractInstance.methods[myFunc](getterFunctionsNameObject[key][j].input).call({from: account1, value: web3.utils.toWei('0', 'ether')})  
  console.log("Normal Order output", res);
  }
```

**output of** `console.log(getterFunctionsNameObject);`

```
[ [ { contract: 0, func: 'balances', input: [Array] },
    { contract: 0, func: 'getTotalSupply', input: [] },
    { contract: 0, func: 'owner', input: [] },
    { contract: 0, func: 'totalSupply', input: [] } ] ]
```

**output of** `console.log(getterFunctionsNameObject[0]);`

```
[ { contract: 0,
    func: 'balances',
    input: [ '0x2cAe18ac37d85CccdE2ebB63D0c391Fe1ac7c36f' ] },
  { contract: 0, func: 'getTotalSupply', input: [] },
  { contract: 0, func: 'owner', input: [] },
  { contract: 0, func: 'totalSupply', input: [] } ]
```

**output of**  `console.log("function Name:  ", myFunc)` : `function Name:   balances` 
**output of** `console.log("param length: ", funcParmLength)`: `param length:  1`
**output of** `console.log("arguments: ", getterFunctionsNameObject[key][j].input)` `arguments:  [ '0x2cAe18ac37d85CccdE2ebB63D0c391Fe1ac7c36f' ]`
**Here is my error:**

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: invalid address (arg="", coderType="address", value=["0x2cAe18ac37d85CccdE2ebB63D0c391Fe1ac7c36f"])
    at Object.throwError (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\ethers\utils\errors.js:68:17)
    at CoderAddress.encode (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\ethers\utils\abi-coder.js:467:20)
    at C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\ethers\utils\abi-coder.js:605:59
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pack (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\ethers\utils\abi-coder.js:604:12)
    at CoderTuple.encode (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\ethers\utils\abi-coder.js:764:16)
    at AbiCoder.encode (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\ethers\utils\abi-coder.js:897:77)
    at ABICoder.encodeParameters (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\web3-eth-abi\src\index.js:96:27)
    at C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\src\index.js:432:24
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object._encodeMethodABI (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\src\index.js:431:12)
    at Object._processExecuteArguments (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\src\index.js:747:39)
    at Object._executeMethod (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\src\index.js:772:54)
    at genericGetterFunction (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\deploy1.js:212:99)
    at main (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\deploy1.js:152:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:6276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:6276) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `getterFunctionsNameObject[key][j].input`, you are passing a single array as input parameter.

Use `...getterFunctionsNameObject[key][j].input` instead.

BTW, I believe that you can use this also for functions which take no input parameters.

In other words, the `if (funcParmLength == 0) / else` part is redundant.

Just do `res = await myContractInstance.methods[myFunc](...getterFunctionsNameObject[key][j].input).call({from: account1, value: web3.utils.toWei('0', 'ether')})`.

BTW2, you don't need to specify `value` when it's zero.

Comment: thank a lot, you always help in better way and very quick....

Comment: by the way, i have one contract which contrains chinese characters, that is not executing, but all others are perfectly done... I think i must have to incorporate some string formatting code like utf-8,....  .